# Compile and Run SDL On Terminal

Tags: c++, ubuntu, sdl

Ok, so I compiled SDL/C++ on terminal easily by just doing:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.out -pthread -std=c++11 `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` .
```

And then this is my main.cpp:

```
// #include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include "SDL2.0.4/SDL2-2.0.4/include/SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    SDL_Window *__window;
    //Init SDL
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    //Creation Window
    __window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "Engine",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        640,
        430,
        SDL_SWSURFACE
    );

    while(true){

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Well when I do `./main.out` to run it, it just stops iterating over while loop. There is no window popping up. I am using Ubuntu Linux. And as I said I want to run and compile sdl on terminal, I'm pretty sure I passed the compiling stage, it's the running that's irritating me.

Comment: are you trying to run an event loop in that `while` loop?

Comment: Nah i really dont care @Mike im doing that while statement so the window dosent quickly open and quickly close, so i can actually see window...

Comment: At a guess, SDL either runs in a co-routine i.e.  you need an sdl call that will cause it to draw.  Try putting in SDL_Delay(100) in your loop.

Comment: @cup im working on the terminal only..  Can we talk over this here? https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/cppwindow . Comment on this topic when your there so i know..

Comment: Why don't you just use debugging methods? There are two points where you can get problems, and luckily, SDL supports error handling. Calling `SDL_init()` will give you back 0 in case of success and a negative value in case of error. If you get negative, you can output SDL's error: `std::cout << SDL_GetError();`. You can get some information from window creation too. Initialize the pointer as NULL and after `SDL_CreateWindow()` you can check, if it's still NULL. In that case call `SDL_GetError()` again. You should get something, because your window does not show up.

Comment: I mean are you sure it will show up like when i execute it on my ubuntu online ide terminal @Lasoloz ?

Comment: @JOHHNYDEP Not sure, but I think you should give a try.